# Is the compiler allowed to modify padding bytes

Tags: c, language-lawyer, padding

Suppose I have a snippet of code like this (and assume that the padding is inserted as I say in the comment):

```
#include "stdint.h"

struct A
{
    uint8_t x;
    // 3 bytes of padding
    uint32_t y;
};


void foo(struct A* a)
{
    a->x = 0;
}
```

Is the compiler allowed to clear the padding bytes or do anything to the padding bytes in the function foo?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object is silent on this issue, which leads me to believe that yes the compiler is allowed to do this....

The reason that I want to know whether or not the compiler is allowed to do this is I want to `memcmp` two structs, and I want to know what I am allowed to assume....

Comment: Why don't you just explicitly declare the padding?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That is a solution, but I don't necessarily want to do that if I don't need to

Comment: You can assume, that the compiler implementation is allowed to add padding bytes as it like and that the amount of bytes can vary from version to version what is called an ABI change. In general you never should use memcpy at all to copy structs as you simply should use copy constructor which is default generated. Internally the compiler typically generates a memcpy for larger structs to copy and calls constructors if needed. If only PODs are used, there is no need for constructor calls. Instead of maintain the need of constructors/destructors you should the compiler do its job alone!

Comment: There is some benefit to declaring the padding explicitly.  The programmer coming after you won't have the same question you just did.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But you can't do it portably.

Comment: If writing words is more efficient than writing bytes on your platform, overwriting padding bytes looks like a reasonable optimization a compiler could do.

Comment: The reason you stated _"what I am allowed to assume...."_ is a little ambiguous.  Your example struct is very simple, but for the general case, depending on the types used, and what addressing boundaries are in effect, assumptions about results of `memcmp()` could be inconclusive wrt where padding exists in the object.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. C 2018 6.2.6.1 6 says:

> When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take unspecified values…

Comment: Does it apply (well, sounds like it does..) to `memcpy`-ing from one `struct` object to another? Like can a `memcmp` following `memcpy` produce a non-zero result?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I think a `memcmp` immediately after a `memcpy` must indicate equality.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Are you sure? Although "unspecified" means the compiler vendor gets to choose what to put in the padding, they may choose to not overwrite the padding bytes, so they may contain garbage.   (of course the `memcpy` will copy the garbage so you're right about the `memcmp`)